# What library to use to extract text from images (OCR)?

Tags: python, ocr

I need to recognize text in images (OCR). What library can I use in Python to extract text from the images?

Comment: For Linux/OSX, check: [OCR on Linux systems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548/ocr-on-linux-systems)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out google [tesseract-oct](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), which has it's own [python module](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/).

Comment: There is also [ocropus](https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)